# Can't get the red creatures into the funnel

Tags: botanicula

So I know that you are supposed to get the tiny red blobs by nuddging them with your mouse. Several guides suggest that when they are close enough to the funnel you push them from underneath. Problem is I can never get them to jump that high, they only jump away from the funnel.

I have tried everything suggested to combat the bugs. Lower screen size, lower cursor quality etc but nothing helps. The creatures just won't jumpo into the funnel.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? I'm pretty sure I finished the game but can't recall the bit you are talking about.